# Mongoose - How to get a value from an array of objects?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I implemented the following Scheme:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  statement: [
      {
        date: Date,
        description: String,
        amount: SchemaTypes.Double,
        balance: SchemaTypes.Double
      }
    ],
});
```

I want to get the balance of the last statement array object. If I query this: `const statement = await User.findById(req.params.id).select("statement");` it returns:

```
{
  "_id": "5cbb934d834d00a955a74081",
  "statement": [
    {
      "date": "2019-05-27T18:15:24.022Z",
      "description": "Account opening",
      "amount": 0,
      "balance": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

However, if I `console.log(statement.statement)` I get the Mongoose object properties instead of the object stored in the array, so I can't do a `statement.statement[-1]`

How can I solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can change the request to this: `User.findById(req.params.id).select("statement.balance")`

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, because now I get an array of balances. However I need to access just the last balance of the array of statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `toJSON` method to get normal JSON object

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toJSON

Also you can't use -1 as an index to the array, to get the last element of an array you can do it like this

```
array.slice(-1)[0]
```

this will return `undefined` in case of empty array

Comment: Perfect, I had to convert `toJSON`, then I could manipulate it as a JSON